# Self Join to compare Old data with New data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to self join a table to list all patients whose information about race or gender has changed during their future visits. A future visit has this condition : PatientVist1.encounter_id < PatientVisit2.encounter_id.  I want the outputs to have have patient number, old and new race values, old and new gender values, and new and old encounter_ids

I believe I start by self joining the patient visit table (pv) to itself
then add in the condition of pv1.encounterid < pv2.encounterid
then add in the visit vital stat table (vvs) twice (another self join)
and compare the pv1.encounterid to vvs1.encounterid
and pv2.encounterid to vvs2.encounterid. I am not sure if this is the right way of thinking about this.

```
PatientVisit Table:

encounter_id patient_nbr
12522   48330783
15738   63555939
16680   42519267
28236   89869032
35754   82637451
36900   77391171
40926   85504905
42570   77586282
55842   84259809
```

```
VisitVitalStat Table:

encounter_id age weight race    gender
12522   [80-90) ?   Caucasian   Female
15738   [90-100)    ?   Caucasian   Female
16680   [40-50) ?   Caucasian   Male
28236   [40-50) ?   AfricanAmerican Female
35754   [50-60) ?   Caucasian   Male
36900   [60-70) ?   AfricanAmerican Male
40926   [40-50) ?   Caucasian   Female
42570   [80-90) ?   Caucasian   Male
55842   [60-70) ?   Caucasian   Male
62256   [60-70) ?   AfricanAmerican Female
``
```

Comment: Reposting yet again. I'll just highlight the fact that your "should look like" image does not help, especially when you mark it with red highlights as if that alone gives guidance to the reader. It certain is NOT helpful to post sample data that does not match your "desired results". You will encourage others to help by posting useful sample data in a consumable format (a fiddle is a good start) as well as a good discussion of your logic. The query that produced your incorrect but marked-up results (presumably) would also help.

Comment: And a better discussion of how to handle a patient that has more than 2 encounters should likely help YOU and everyone else. What happens when a mistake is made and then corrected? E.g., race was "x", accidentally changed to "y", and then changed back to "x". Similarly, race was "x", changed to "y" and then changed to "z".

Comment: The old gender and age are just the original columns from VisitVitalPatient. The new gender and age columns are what is produced after the condition pv1.encounterid < pv2.encounterid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to use a table in the same query, just use "aliases" to differentiate between the first and the second.

Joining on the same patient is one thing, but then only consider the second table to have the encounter GREATER THAN the one in the first alias.  Otherwise, if a patient has encounters 1, 2, 3, your results would show [1,2] [1,3] [2,1]-duplicate, [2,3], [3,1]-duplicate, [3,2]-duplicate..  So by having the greater than, you would only have [1,2], [1,3] and [2,3] in your result set

```
select
      pv1.patient_nbr,
      pv1.encounter_id as EncounterIDFirst,
      pv2.encounter_id as EncounterIDSecond,
      vs1.age AgeFirst,
      vs2.age AgeSecond,
      vs1.weight WeightFirst,
      vs2.weight WeightSecond,
      vs1.race RaceFirst,
      vs2.race RaceSecond,
      vs1.gender GenderFirst,
      vs2.gender GenderSecond
   from
      PatientVisit pv1
         JOIN VisitVitalStat vs1
            on pv1.encounter_id = vs1.encounter_id
         JOIN PatientVisit pv2
            -- ensure same patient first
            on pv1.patient_nbr = pv2.patient_nbr
           AND pv1.encounter_id < pv2.encounter_id
            JOIN VisitVitalStat vs2
                on pv2.encounter_id = vs2.encounter_id
   where
      NOT   (  vs1.age = vs2.age
           AND vs1.weight = vs2.weight
           AND vs1.race = vs2.race
           AND vs1.gender = vs2.gender )
```

Notice the WHERE clause.  I am explicitly looking for NOT where (all the elements are the SAME ).  So, if any ONE of the 4 possibilities is different, it will be returned in the result set.

So, start your query with the from/join conditions.  HOW to things get related and on what keys.  THEN consider the where that you are looking for.  Now that all is good, and you have very simple "alias" table references, pull the columns and name them as you need.